# Undefined Switch Case in Functions in C++

Tags: c++, function, switch-statement, undefined

I'm doing a scrolling menu, this is the code of my scrolling menu:

```
vector<string> menuVector;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){
    menuVector.push_back("Login");
    menuVector.push_back("Exit");

    scrollingMenu_();

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

void scrollingMenu_(){
    ShowConsoleCursor(false);

    int pointer = 0;

    while (true){
        system("cls");

        SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 15);

        welcome();

        for (int i = 0; i < menuVector.size(); ++i){
            if (i == pointer){
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 8);
                cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t> " << center(menuVector[i], 5) << " <" << endl;
            }
            else{
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 15);
                cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t  " << center(menuVector[i], 5) << "  " << endl;
            }
        }

        while (true){
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) != 0){
                pointer -= 1;

                //if menu option selected is before the first option, it will back to the last menu option
                if (pointer == -1){
                    pointer = menuVector.size() - 1;
                }
                break;
            }
            else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN) != 0){
                pointer += 1;

                //if menu option selected is after the last option, it will back to the first menu option
                if (pointer == menuVector.size()){
                    pointer = 0;
                }
                break;
            }
            else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN) != 0){
                switch (pointer){ //this is the switch case
                case 0:
                    cout << "\n\n\nStarting new game...";
                    Sleep(1000);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    exit(0);
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        Sleep(150);
    }
}
```

As for the case switch inside my `scrollingMenu_()` function, the switch case will not be the same sometime I called the function, is there something like `scrollingMenu_(switchcase)`, so by that time when I'm calling the function then I can define what my switchcase will do. Otherwise I have to copy paste the same `scrollingMenu()` function code for the parts that I need to do a menu with different menu options, which looks kinda redundant. I tried to research it online, but I didn't know how to search so I didn't get what I want.

Thank you.

Comment: To avoid code duplication, consider - tadaa - "functions". It's magic, they let you reuse the same code in multiple places but only write it once - incredible!

Comment: @JesperJuhl and it's much better than `goto` and `gosub`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to be able to have different "menus" in your vector, and therefore be able to do different things in the `switch` depending on what menu is currently "active"?

Then I suggest a completely different design. Instead of a vector of strings for the menu, and a `switch` statement to select between the behaviors, use *two* vectors: One for the menu text (like you already have), and one for the menu "actions".

Then instead of using a `switch` to select between the actions for a menu alternative, simply use the `pointer` as an index into the second vector to call the action.

You can do this quite easily with [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) in combination with [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) or [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

---

For the menu you currently have it would be something like

```
std::vector<std::function<void()>> actionVector;

// ...

// Set up the menu vectors for the current menu
menuVector = {
    "Login",
    "Exit"
};

actionVector = {
    []() { cout << "\n\n\nStarting new game..."; Sleep(1000); },
    []() { std::exit(0); }
};

scrollingMenu_();

// ...

else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN) != 0){
    actionVector[pointer]();  // Call the action
}
```

Comment: another approach would be create some tree-like structure where some items might refer to list of next level's items to be dispayed... that way depth of nesting and menu structure can be dynamic

Comment: @Swift That would of course be better, but I went for the (relatively) easy solution.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah, I know, it was comment for expanding OP's outlook, not for you. Also, in university I got horrified by perspective of dealing with large switches and arrays (no classes allowed!), so I cheated and made tree with function pointers as handlers, because it was easier. Tutor's reaction was "Alright, you cheated and rediscovered old way. I like that"